# Cannot read property '_syncPendingControls' of undefined angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm getting an error on form submit in angular 6

my code is

```
<form [formGroup]="businessForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" id="bus-form">
    ....// some inputs
    <button type=submit>Next</button>
</form>
```

component

```
businessForm = this.fb.group({
    proof: ['', Validators.required]
});
defaultValue;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}
ngOnInit() {
    this.businessForm.controls.proof = this.defaultValue;
}
submitForm() {}
```

error is

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_syncPendingControls' of undefined
    at VM42524 account-setting-account-setting-module~landing-landing-module~registration-registration-module.js:3292
    at VM42524 account-setting-account-setting-module~landing-landing-module~registration-registration-module.js:3344
    at VM42524 account-setting-account-setting-module~landing-landing-module~registration-registration-module.js:3310
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FormGroup.push.../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroup._forEachChild (VM42524 account-setting-account-setting-module~landing-landing-module~registration-registration-module.js:3310)
    at FormGroup.push.../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroup._reduceChildren (VM42524 account-setting-account-setting-module~landing-landing-module~registration-registration-module.js:3344)
    at FormGroup.push.../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroup._syncPendingControls (VM42524 account-setting-account-setting-module~landing-landing-module~registration-registration-module.js:3291)
    at VM42524 account-setting-account-setting-module~landing-landing-module~registration-registration-module.js:3292
    at VM42524 account-setting-account-setting-module~landing-landing-module~registration-registration-module.js:3344
    at VM42524 account-setting-account-setting-module~landing-landing-module~registration-registration-module.js:3310
```

if anyone getting this error please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: show the component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in initializing form control name proof in ngOnInit function

you need to update this initialization as follow

```
this.businessForm.controls.proof.patchValue(this.defaultValue);
```